# Can I use eclipse to write j2me code?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, java-me, j2mepolish

please guys, before I download eclipse, is it possible to use it to compile j2me code, or it is used only for android applications?

I am finding netbeans difficult to work with and I was wondering if eclipse was easier. I am new, I need help to start up writing j2me as well as using netbeans or eclipse, I am confused, I am trying to use netbeans, but I don't understand it. Is eclipse easier and j2me compatible?

Comment: There is a plugin called **EclipseME** for Eclipse for Java developer. Download here: http://eclipseme.org/

Comment: Download [Pulsar for Mobile Developers.](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/pulsar-mobile-developers/heliossr1) And download the sun java toolkit [here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html) Then add the this toolkit into eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Mobile Tools for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/mtj/) - it's the evolution of the EclipseME plugin.  You can definitely do all your J2ME things with this package.

Answer (score 1):

first install WTK `sun_java_wireless_toolkit`

download eclipse IDE and install after u start the eclipse you follow this instruction

1. Help->Select Install new software or (update software)
2. It leads to a new window, then select the Add button.
3. Enter the link http://www.eclipseme.org/updates and then click ok button.
4. Then select the next button. After then some process completes then the eclipseme plugin with the eclipse tool.

Then follow the below link instructions

http://eclipseme.org/docs/configuring.html