# Configure Eclipse for J2ME development

Tags: eclipse, java-me, configure, eclipseme

I've recently started learning J2ME. I'm not able to run the j2me code in eclipse. I'm not sure how to configure eclipse to run j2me in it. I could use EclipseME, but I'd like to configure the eclipse I'm using to run j2me rather than installing a separate app for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the [Eclipse Pulsar](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/pulsar-mobile-developers/heliossr1) and configure [Sun java toolkit.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html) For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290505/can-i-use-eclipse-to-write-j2me-code) existing discussion.