# setting up Eclipse IDE with WTK properly

Tags: java-me, java-wireless-toolkit, eclipseme

I just started with J2ME and have a good experience with J2SE.
I've been using Eclipse IDE (Helios-x64) for building Java Applications.
My Laptop has Windows 7 (x64) installed with Intel Core i3.

I've done good research over internet before setting up and found that WTK is a 32 bit Toolkit, so I installed 32 bit JDK and also downloaded 32 Eclipse IDE (Indigo).

Now, I've installed JDK, WTK and EclipseME in Eclipse IDE, however i'm unable to change config.ini for pre-processor support as guided by the EclipseME installation, because, on doing so eclipse won't start.

Now, after everything configured according to the Installation manual, when I try to start the first line of code (i.e., `import javax.microedition.midlet.*`), Eclipse gives me an error that says import can't be resolved.

Probably because even after installing EclipseME and setting the root directory, Eclipse is still not able to locate the corret packages.

Please help me, I've been messing with all these thing from more than 12 hours and now I'm not willing to learn J2ME because of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the exact reason. But you can download the [Eclipse Pulsar](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/pulsar-mobile-developers/heliossr1) and configure [Sun java toolkit.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html) For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290505/can-i-use-eclipse-to-write-j2me-code) existing discussion.